# How to change the order of integration of this triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

So the question goes as follows:

Change the order of integration of the following integral:
$$ \int_{\frac{-12}{7}}^{7}\int_{0}^{7-y}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{7y+12}} f(x,y,z)dxdzdy $$ to $\to$
$$\int_{?}^{?}\int_{?}^{?}\int_{?}^{?} f(x,y,z)dydzdx $$

**My answer (which partly is right, I hope)**
$$\int_{\frac{-12}{7}}^{0}\int_{0}^{7}\int_{\frac{-12}{7}}^{7-z} f(x,y,z)dydzdx $$

**My question**
Could someone please verify if my answer is wrong and were my mistake exactly takes place. I spend a lot of time drawing this, and tried to transfer this to the triple integral. But I made an error somewhere along the path. The reason I know I made a mistake is because I calculated both triple integrals and got two different numerical values. If someone could show me the answer and tell me how you got there it would very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
:)

**drawing**

> [image]

Comment: There is no function of x in bounds, may be upper bound of second integral is (7-x). the upper and lower bounds must be functions of a single variable, if the upper bound of third integral is $\sqrt{7y+12}$, the upper bound of second integral can not be $7-y$.

Comment: If you take lower bound of $y$ a constant, you will not be bound by the parabolic cylinder and you will be integrating over a different region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are integrating over $dy$ first, the lower bound of $y$ is given by the parabolic cylinder $x = \sqrt{7y+12}$ and upper bound is given by plane $y+z = 7$.

Next for $dz$, the lower limit of $z$ is zero. For upper limit of $z$, find the intersection of the plane and the parabolic cylinder,

$y = \frac{x^2-12}{7} = 7 - z \implies z = \frac{61-x^2}{7}$.

Lastly for $dx$, the lower limit of $x$ is zero. The upper bound of $x$ is when $z = 0$, which is $x = \sqrt{61}$.

So the integral translates to,

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\sqrt{61}}\int_{0}^{(61-x^2)/7}\int_{(x^2-12)/7}^{7-z} f(x,y,z) \ dy \ dz \ dx$

Answer (score 1):

When the triple integral is of the form $dxdzdy$ with the limits of x and z dependent only on y, you can be formulaic about it. First draw 2D plots of y on the horizontal axis and x on the vertical axis, and y on the horizontal axis and z on the vertical axis. If you cut out the z-y plot and place it vertically-perpendicularly to the x-y plot, you should be able to visualize that the left (lower) limit of y is with the x-y curve at $\sqrt{7y+12}=x\implies y=\frac{x^2-12}{7}$ and that the right (upper) limit of y is with the z-y curve at $z=7-y\implies y=7-z$. Now we have one remaining dependency of $z$ on $x$, this can be found by the limits of integration. $$0<z<7-y\\0<x<\sqrt{7y+12}$$
implies
$$0>7-z>y\\-12<\frac{x^2-12}{7}<y$$

which combined give $0<z<\frac{61-x^2}{7}<19$. Finally, the limits on x are from 0 to $\sqrt{7(7)+12}=\sqrt{61}$. So the limits of integration are

$$\frac{x^2-12}{7}<y<7-z\\
0<z<\frac{61-x^2}{7}\\
0<x<\sqrt{61}$$